# ApplicationData.ClearAsync() doesn't work in Windows 8.1 Universal App

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, winrt-async

I'm trying to clear the application data when user logout of the application & I found ApplicationData.ClearAsync() which fits my requirement which is similar to IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Clear() but it gives me an below error

An exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020)

I'm not able to understand this as there is no file that I have opened or using as I'm simply using as isolatedstorage just in key value pair.

Kindly help me figure out how I can solve this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It may fail if you have images used in your xaml for instance : is it the case ? One solution I ended up was to clear ApplicationData on the next launch.

You could also list the files and try to delete them one by one.

Comment: Yes I do have images in my XAML & clearning ApplicationData on next launch doesn't serve my purpose as I have two types of login guest & member hence I need to have it clear once the user logout. And as I have said earlier I'm not storing any file in applicationdata I'm using it as plain isolatedstorage which keeps the data in key value pairs

Comment: So your issue is fixed ?

Comment: No, but the project is no longer in development as even my company has drop support for Windows Mobile. But still if you have the answer provide the same so someone else can be benefited. If not the thread can be closed.